# Error when I try enabling all origins for CORS

Tags: spring-boot

I have enabled CORS to allow all origins, however when I try login, it will produce an error stating. I tried '.allowedOriginPatterns("*")''' however same outcome. I am able to individually add each origin pattern however I want to know how to do all.

**Messages:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns(".*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}

'''
```

Comment: Can you please add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Comment: Are you using spring security as well?